# ios bookmark icons per subdirectory

Tags: html

I have a number of simple tools I created to make tasks on my (i)phone a bit easier. I have placed these tools on my webserver in different directories:

- sub.domain.tld/tool1
- sub.domain.tld/tool2
- sub.domain.tld/tool3

Next I created bookmarks for each tool so they show up when opening my safari browser. I have added the following code for a favicon:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="icon.png">
```

Strange thing is, all tools show the same icon, where they all have different icons (and thus another meta tag). It seems the icon is set when adding the tool to my bookmarks, and is changed to whatever is the tool that is used the most.

Can I force the icon?